# Nesting modules inside of a Rails eninge gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

What is the proper syntax to nest child modules within a parent module that is being is an isolate_namespace Rails engine gem?

```
# lib/myengine/engine.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Myengine
    # def ...
  end
end
```

For example. The parent module is MyEngine and the child module is Blog. MyEngine will share common domain, like CRUD, Taggable, Searchable, etc, which will keep the gem code DRY and isolated from the main app (MyApp), while inheriting the isolated namespace and Engine.

Are either of the two approaches correct? Any refactor advice?

```
# A
# lib/myengine/blog.rb
module MyEngine
  module Blog
    # def ...
  end
end

# B
# lib/myengine/blog.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Myengine
    module Blog
      # def ...
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option A. is correct, but it should be `lib/my_engine/blog.rb`. You can read more about Ruby & Rails naming conventions [here](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7).

Further, if you want to put more modules or classes under the blog namespace you put them in the folder `lib/my_engine/blog` and nest them under `MyEngine::Blog`.